# What is the practical significance of a linear regression, lasso regression, and ridge regression outputting the same coefficients?

Tags: regression, lasso

The lasso and ridge regression are tuned to the same alpha parameter. No matter what I tune the parameter to [0,1], the results of all three regressions are always the same (linear, ridge, lasso), which is a bit befuddling because I had previously suspected that there was some multicollinearity in my data due to high variance inflation factors. I thought that either the lasso or ridge would address the issue of multicollinearity, but this does not seem to be the case. If anyone can provide some insight that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you precise something about your data ? What is the dimension of the data ? What about the goodness of fit of the OLS regression ?

Comment: There's not enough information here to discern what's happening. A reproducible minimal example (i.e. the smallest example that shows the problem you describe) might throw light on what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this question without more specific information, but it's important to understand that that if the parameter in ridge regression or LASSO is too small, then you'll get back very nearly the same answer as with linear regression.

For example, suppose that in ridge regression you're minimzing

$\min \| X \beta - y \|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \| \beta \|_{2}^{2}$

with $\lambda=1$, and that in the optimal solution, $\| \beta \|_{2}=10$, but 
$\| X \beta - y \|_{2}=10000000$.  In this case, the ridge regression penalty term is so small as to be insignificant in comparison to the linear regression term and you'll end up with essentially the same answer with or without the penalty term.

So, in your examples, what is the size of $\| X \beta -y \|_{2}$?  What about the ridge regression and LASSO penalty terms?